# Entity Framework can't understand foreign key and trying add "_Id" column to query

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, orm, mapping

I am trying to map two table through one.
Here is image with database structure:
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/18024879/31611981-e77d51ae-b286-11e7-8aae-02394d12631a.png

Here is my models:

```
public class Notification
    {
        public Notification()
        {
            Accounts = new HashSet<Account>();
        }
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public NotificationType NotificationType { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
        public virtual NotificationModelRequest NotificationModelRequest { get; set; }
    }

    public class NotificationModelRequest
    {
        public Guid NotificationId { get; set; }
        public Guid ModelId { get; set; }
        public Guid AccountId { get; set; }
        public virtual Notification Notification { get; set; }
        public virtual Model Model { get; set; }
        public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
    }
    public partial class Model
    {
        public Guid id { get; set; }
        public virtual NotificationModelRequest NotificationModelRequest { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Account
    {
         public Account()
        {
            Notifications = new HashSet<Notification>();
        }
        public Guid id { get; set; }
        public virtual NotificationModelRequest NotificationModelRequest { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my mappings:

```
    public NotificationConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("Notification");
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        Property(x => x.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        Property(x => x.NotificationType);

        HasMany(e => e.Accounts)
            .WithMany(c => c.Notifications)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapLeftKey("NotificationId");
                m.MapRightKey("AccountId");
                m.ToTable("AccountNotifications");
            });

        Ignore(x => x.ModelName);
        Ignore(x => x.CreatedBy);

        HasRequired(x => x.NotificationModelRequest).WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.Notification);
    }

    public NotificationModelRequestConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("NotificationModelRequest");
        HasKey(x => x.NotificationId);

        Property(t => t.ModelId).HasColumnName("ModelId");
        Property(t => t.AccountId).HasColumnName("AccountId");

        HasRequired(x => x.Model).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.ModelId);
        HasRequired(x => x.Account).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.AccountId);
    }

    public AccountConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("Account");
        HasKey(x => x.id);
    }

    public ModelConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("Model");
        HasKey(x => x.id);
    }
```

When i am trying make include the nested properties i have error:

```
    public async Task<List<Notification>> GetNotificationByAccountId(Guid accountId)
    {
        var query = GetQuery()
            .Include(x => x.NotificationModelRequest)
            .Include(x => x.NotificationModelRequest.Model)
            .Include(x => x.NotificationModelRequest.Account)
            .Include(x => x.Accounts);

        var testQuery = _context.Set<NotificationModelRequest>()
            .Include(x => x.Model)
            .Include(x => x.Account);
        var test = testQuery.FirstOrDefault();

        return await query.ToListAsync();
    }

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
Invalid column name 'NotificationModelRequest_NotificationId'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 37
Invalid column name 'NotificationModelRequest_NotificationId'.
```

Could you please help how to i have to write this mapping?
Thanks.

Comment: Why doesn't Account have a collection of NotificationModelRequests?

Comment: Yes, thank you! It was helpful.